# Looping through Outlook folder, and moving items, misses one email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to loop through a specific folder in Outlook and for each email:
(1) Save every attachment to a specific location. Most emails only have one.
(2) Move the email to a specific subfolder.

The following code doesn't process one email. If there are three emails in the folder, it processes two.

```vb
Dim OlApp                          
Dim OlMail                         
Dim OlItems                       
Dim Olfolder                       
Dim OlSubfolder                    
Dim MyNameSpace
Dim J As Integer
Dim strFolder As String
Dim MyFileName() As String
Dim EmailCount As Integer
Dim X As Integer

Set OlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If

strFolder = ""
strFolder = "C:\Temp\MarketPay\"
    
Set MyNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Olfolder = MyNameSpace.Folders.Item("Efficiency Tools").Folders.Item("Inbox").Folders.Item("HomePay").Items

Set OlSubfolder = MyNameSpace.Folders("Efficiency Tools").Folders("Inbox").Folders("HomePay").Folders("Completed")

//only used to validate the number of emails in the folder
EmailCount = 0
EmailCount = Olfolder.Count
    
X = 1
    
For Each OlMail In Olfolder

    DoEvents
    
    For J = 1 To OlMail.Attachments.Count
                        
        ReDim Preserve MyFileName(1 To X)
                
        MyFileName(X) = OlMail.Attachments.Item(J)
                
        OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).SaveAsFile strFolder & OlMail.Attachments.Item(J)
                
        OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).SaveAsFile strFolder & OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).FileName
                
        X = X + 1
                
    Next J
    
    OlMail.Move OlSubfolder

Next
```

The attachment is is a csv file that is autogenerated each day. The emails are the same except for the date in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You should not loop through a collection using an enumerator (`for each`) while also modifying it (by moving messages).

Change the loop from

```
For Each OlMail In Olfolder
```

to a down loop:

```
for i = Olfolder.Count to 1 step -1
  set OlMail = Olfolder(i)
```

Comment: .........Thanks........I'll give that a try and let you know how it works for me......shaves

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the Outlook folder is not really a good idea:

```
For Each OlMail In Olfolder
```

Instead, if you need to find all items with attachments and iterate over them you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting items that correspond to the specified search criteria, for example, to get items with attachments you can use the following search string:

```
query ="@SQL=" & chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & chr(34) & "=1"
```

In the code I've noticed multiple lines of code with repeatable code, for example:

```
MyFileName(X) = OlMail.Attachments.Item(J)
                
MyFileName(X).SaveAsFile strFolder & MyFileName(X)

MyFileName(X).SaveAsFile strFolder & MyFileName(X).FileName
```

It makes sense to re-use the same object if you have already retrieved it.

```
MyFileName(X) = OlMail.Attachments.Item(J)
                
OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).SaveAsFile strFolder & OlMail.Attachments.Item(J)
OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).SaveAsFile strFolder & OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).FileName
```

Be aware, the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method accepts a string which represents the location at which to save the attachment. So, there you need to be sure that a valid file path is passed:

```
MyFileName(X).SaveAsFile strFolder & MyFileName(X)
```

Finally, to remove or move items from the collection I'd suggest using the reverse for loop so your index could always point to a valid item in the collection.

Comment: .........I'll try these suggestions as well to solve the issue.  Thanks for your help..